# specialized DictionaryIterator._nativeNext() crash

Tags: swift, dictionary

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x722f73726573552f
```

Part of code crash happened:

```
var totalNotifications : [Int : UserNotification] = [Int : UserNotification]()
func getPendingInvitesCount() -> Int
    {     
        AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().log.debug("getPendingInvitesCount()")

        var count = 0
        for notification in totalNotifications {
            if notification.1.msgClassName == RideInvitation.rideInviteMessageClassName {
                count += 1
            }
        }
            return count
    }
}
```

The app was crashing in the below lines:

```
for notification in totalNotifications {
    var totalNotifications : [Int : UserNotification] = [Int : UserNotification]()  
}
```

I declared totalNotifications as:

```
var totalNotifications : [Int : UserNotification] = [Int : UserNotification]()
```

Because of this app was crashing, I tried a lot but I could not able to analyze why crash has happened in the declaration of the dictionary, please help me to find the solution. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var totalNotifications : [Int : UserNotification] = Int : UserNotification` What's that declaration? Did you meant `var totalNotifications : [Int : UserNotification] = [:]` to initialize it?

Comment: sorry this is the  declaration where crash happened var totalNotifications : [Int : UserNotification] = [Int : UserNotification]()